# 'setCurrentItem' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, compiler-errors

In app.js the code is,

```
import './App.css';
import Todoform from './Components/Todoform';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="To-Do App">
     <Todoform />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in Todoform.js the code is,

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Todoform() {
    const [currentItem,setCurrentItem]= useState(null);

    return (
      <form className='To-do'>
       <input 
          type='text'
          placeholder='Add a todo'
          value={currentItem}
          name='text'
          className='to-do input' 
      />
      <button className="to-do button">Add To-do</button>
      </form>
    );
}

export default Todoform;
```

When I execute the code, an error is showing as follows, 'setCurrentItem' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) error.

What should I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules on eslintrc.json.
warn or off is your choice.

```
...
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    
  }
```